# Why does the character of a representation have the same parity as the dimension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Assume that $ \phi: G \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a group representation and denote the character of the representation as $ \chi_{\phi}(g) = Tr(\phi_g)$.

In my notes I assume that if $ n $ is even, then $Tr(\phi_g)$ is even, and in the same way odd, odd. Why is this true?

This is true for the trivial representation, $ \phi: G \to \mathbb{C}^{\times} $, and I've only considered groups with even order, $D_n, S_n$ so the regular representation $ \chi_{\phi}(g) = \begin{cases}n, \quad \text{g = id} \\ 0 \quad \text{else} \end{cases}$ fullfills this too.

For clarification, it is written [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Determination_of_character_table_of_alternating_group:A5), under **Determining the characters** - **Filling in the column of order two elements**

> The character value has the same parity as the degree (so it is odd for odd-dimensional representation, and even for even-dimensional representations)

So my question is rather, why is this?

Comment: What do you mean by the character being even? That $\chi(g)=\chi(g^{-1})?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: No, under that interpretation the trivial representation would be even, not odd.

Comment: That quote doesn’t clarify if what the parity of the character means, it just asserts what you said is true?

Comment: Also, that quote is from a passage that deals very specifically with elements of order $2$; it doesn't claim that this holds in general.

Comment: Yes, that passage is about a specific case - when all the eigenvalues are real, and thus all are $\pm 1$ and the character is an integer sum of $n$ values $\pm 1,$ which is thus the same parity as $n.$

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. For instance, the symmetric group $S_3$ has a two-dimensional irreducible representation whose character on the $3$-cycles is $2\cos\frac{2\pi}3=-1$. (You can obtain it by letting the group act on the vertices of a triangle.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've edited the post to clarify the question

Comment: @Oskar: As far as I can tell, the question was clear enough. I provided a counterexample to your claim.